# encoded url: %9A showing up as ?-diamond ... how to get browser to correctly interpret %9A

Tags: flash, browser, encoding, urlrequest, navigatetourl

I am generating a url (for facebook dialog) from flash:

```
var lvs_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=208524139202627&name=š š&caption=&description=&link=http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle/"
var lvo_req : URLRequest = new URLRequest( lvs_url ) ;
navigateToURL( lvo_req , "_blank" );
```

but by the time that url makes it to the browser, the **š**'s have been turned into **%9A**'s, which then show up as **?-diamond**'s in the facebook pop up.

However, the browser is ok with **%20**'s

here is the encoded url: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=208524139202627&name=%9A%20%9A&caption=&description=&link=http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle/

Comment: `0x9A` is not valid UTF-8 byte sequence. How did you create it? It should be `%C5%A1` for `š`

Comment: it was apparently created by the flash AS3 **var lvo_req : URLRequest = new URLRequest( lvs_url )** because it was a **š** going in, but a **%9A** by the time it got to the browser address bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var lvs_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=208524139202627&name="+encodeURIComponent("š š")+"&caption=&description=&link=http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/celjska_puzzle/";
var lvo_req : URLRequest = new URLRequest( lvs_url ) ;
navigateToURL( lvo_req , "_blank" );
```

---

From [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#URLRequest()) :

> Creates a URLRequest object.
>
> If `System.useCodePage` is `true`, the request is encoded using the
> system code page, rather than Unicode.
>
> If `System.useCodePage` is `false`, the request is encoded using
> Unicode, rather than the system code page.

[Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-21) says:

> Non-ASCII    characters must first be encoded according to UTF-8
> [STD63], and then    each octet of the corresponding UTF-8 sequence
> must be percent-    encoded to be represented as URI characters.

This means that `"š"` must be encoded as `%C5%A1` in urls. Try setting `System.useCodePage` to `false`, even though the documentation is ambiguous because *encoded using Unicode*  doesn't necessarily mean `UTF-8`.

I should also mention that your file should be saved in `UTF-8` encoding if you are literally using `"š"` in the file.

Comment: **1** - _System.useCodePage = false_ ... did not help

**2** - _Non-ASCII characters must first be encoded according to UTF-8 [STD63], and then each octet of the corresponding UTF-8 sequence must be percent- encoded to be represented as URI characters._ ... I'm sorry but I have no idea what this means 

**3** - _This means that "š" must be encoded as %C5%A1_ ... when I literally put that into a browser address bar it worked, but of course my urls are being built dynamically in flash with all sorts of characters, so I can't hardcode.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd can you clarify, did it change anything at all? Or do you mean it was already at false. Have you saved your file in UTF-8?

Comment: my flash Edit/Preferences/Actionscript/open-import and save-export are set to utf-8.
...
Right now I am reading about URLRequest.contentType ...

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Do you mean you still got `%9A` after setting `System.useCodePage` to `false`?

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd I just found out that AS3 should have the function `encodeURIComponent` (same as javascript), you can try that

Comment: _encodeURI_ worked ... if you will make this into an answer I can 'check' it ... ... ... EDIT: oh I see you already did.